# Source file is not valid UTF-8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting build error : **Source file is not valid UTF-8** for particular file.

I had attached screenshot for more information.

[image]

Source Code:

```
 @interface DetailCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSize;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCount;

@end
```

Comment: I'd suggest right clicking on the source file and choose "Open As" - "Hex" and then show us what's there. It's a way to look at the contents of a file, byte by byte...

Comment: @Rob here is my hex code : https://gist.github.com/SunnyShah407/ce9ceaa2a9698a4b13d8f1a5c747b250

Comment: Is DetailCell.h the original header file or is it an alias?  The preview image suggests it is an alias.

Comment: The hex you shared with us is valid UTF8. But I wonder about the shortcut icon, too...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your link. 
You need to create a symlink rather than an alias.

here is an explanation re the differences between types of links

https://www.lifewire.com/aliases-symbolic-links-hard-links-mac-2260189

and here explanation about how to create a symlink

https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe